# For what values of x is $a(x)\cos(f(x))+b(x)\sin(g(x))=\sqrt{(a(x))^2+(b(x))^2-2a(x)b(x)(\sin(f(x)-g(x)))}\sin[(f(x)+g(x))/2+\arctan(c(x)/d(x))]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $c(x)=a(x)\cos(v(x))-b(x)\sin(v(x))$, $d(x)=b(x)\cos(v(x))-a(x)\sin(v(x))$.

It can be shown by expanding that $$[a(x)\cos(f(x))+b(x)\sin(g(x))]^{2}=(\sqrt{(a(x))^2+(b(x))^2-2a(x)b(x)(\sin(f(x)-g(x)))}\sin[(f(x)+g(x))/2+\arctan(c(x)/d(x))])^{2}.$$

So, on some intervals

$$a(x)\cos(f(x))+b(x)\sin(g(x))=\sqrt{(a(x))^2+(b(x))^2-2a(x)b(x)(\sin(f(x)-g(x)))}\sin[(f(x)+g(x))/2+\arctan(c(x)/d(x))],$$

whereas on other intervals

$$a(x)\cos(f(x))+b(x)\sin(g(x))=-\sqrt{(a(x))^2+(b(x))^2-2a(x)b(x)(\sin(f(x)-g(x)))}\sin[(f(x)+g(x))/2+\arctan(c(x)/d(x))].$$

This may very well be a bit of a dumb question, but how can I tell on which intervals to use the positive square root versus the negative square root? Obviously it ultimately depends on $a(x), b(x), f(x)$ and $g(x)$, but what equations in terms of those functions can I solve in order to determine exactly when to use the positive square root or the negative square root?

Here's a bit of progress I made.

Suppose a and b are constant coefficients and $f(x)=g(x)=x$.
By testing out all possible combinations of a,b (-,-), (-,+), (+,-), (+,+), you can deduce the following:

If b is nonnegative, then
$$a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin((x)+\arctan(a/b)).$$

If b negative, then
$$a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)=-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin((x)+\arctan(a/b)).$$

Comment: next time please use ``\`` before trigonometric functions

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the answer you were hoping for… You could take $h(x)=\pi/2$ and $c(x) = a\cos(f(x)) + b\sin(g(x))$.

Comment: Do you know whether or not there exists another example?

Comment: Sure, you can try $h(x) = 5\pi/2$ instead. Other than that? Why not $c(x)= a\cos(f)\csc(g) +b$ and $h(x)= g$. There are infinitely many solutions of course…

Comment: My question is a bit too trivial to be asking then. I suppose I could redirect this to instead focus on calculating the intervals on which to use the positive or negative square root for the expression I came up with. Or is that also a trivial question?

Comment: Your question is sneaking up on something interesting, I think, Simon. A combination of sine and cosine like $3 \sin(x) + 5 \cos(x)$ turns out to look like a sine wave, somewhat offset and scaled, i.e., it looks like $k \sin(x  + d)$, and finding $k$ and $d$ is kind of interesting. But what happens if the argument ($x$) in the first formula "changes direction?" -- do you have to adjust $k$ or $d$ in the second, or adjust $x$ in the second in some way? In a slightly more general context, this was an early challenge in complex analysis, and led to the notion of "analytic continuation."

Comment: Using the method I chose:
$3 \sin(x) + 5 \cos(x)=\sqrt{3^2+5^2}\sin(x+\arctan(5/3))$. So on any interval, one would choose the positive square root instead of the negative square root. I think I'm comfortable with doing this for linear combinations of sines and cosines all of whose arguments are equal. Where it gets confusing for me is when  there are no longer constant coefficients on the sines and cosines and their arguments are arbitrary functions of x.

Comment: If the argument $(x)$ were replaced with $(-x)$ then $3\sin(-x)+5\cos(-x)=-3\sin(x)+5\cos(x)$. Then, using my result for when b is negative: $3\sin(-x)+5\cos(-x)=-3\sin(x)+5\cos(x)=\sqrt{(-3)^2+5^2}\sin[x+arctan(5/(-3))]$